# count Table rows which have non-empty textbox

Tags: jquery

How to count the number of table rows which are having non-empty textbox in its `<td>`?

I have tried something like below but it counts all the rows.

`$("#sample_table input[value!=\"\"]").closest("tr",$(this)).length;`

Comment: can you provide your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the `tr` elements.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

*Code*

```
var trElements = $("#sample_table tr").filter(function(){
    //Get Non Empty inputs
    var nonEmptyInputs = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').filter(function(){
        return this.value.length > 0; 
    });

    return nonEmptyInputs.length > 0
});

var noOfNonEmptyTrs = trElements.length;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var trElements = $("#sample_table tr").filter(function() {
      //Get Non Empty inputs
      var nonEmptyInputs = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
        return this.value.length > 0;
      });
      return nonEmptyInputs.length;
    });

    console.log(trElements.length);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">GET COUNT</button>
<table id="sample_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you snippet is always returning 0 as length even i entered some values in text box.

Comment: @kumar_v, There was a small error in snippet, updated answer with working example

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
function countNotEmptyRows() {
  var notEmptyRows = $('tr').filter(function(idx, element) {
    return $(element).find('td input').val() != '';
  });

  return notEmptyRows.length;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert(countNotEmptyRows())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="not empty">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

For number of non empty input -

```
  var count = $('#sample_table tr td input').filter(function(){
       return $(this).val();
    }).length;
```

For number of rows which are having non-empty textbox -

```
var count = $('#sample_table tr').filter(function(){
      return $(this).find('input').filter(function(){
        return $(this).val();
             }).length > 0;

    }).length;
```

here is the updated example :
https://jsfiddle.net/39jcjobv/4/

Comment: Add two textbox in a row and run your script. It will count the text boxes. Not rows.